# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\ M_n =M$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am study analysis, I beginning absolute value of integrable functions, and see that problem:

If $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous, non-negative function, and

$M=\max \{f(x): x\in [0,1]\}$ and $M_n = (\int_0^1 f^n)^{1/n}$, n=1,2....

Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\ M_n =M$

I think that, first I prove that $M_n$ converge and them I prove that converge to $\max \{f(x)\}$ but I don´t know how I prove that $M_n$ converge.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline (hints) for a proof:

- Since $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$ the [extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) tells us that $f$ attains its maximum $M$ on $[0,1]$. Let $x_*$ be any point where $f(x_*) = M$.
- Since $f$ is continuous then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a $\delta >0$ s.t. if $|x-x_*| < \delta$ then $|f-M| < \epsilon$.
- This implies (why?) that $M^n \geq \int_0^1 f^ndx \geq \int_{\text{max}(0,x_*-\delta)}^{\text{min}(1,x_*+\delta)} f^ndx \geq (M-\epsilon)^n\delta $.
- Take the $n$'th root and then the limit $n\to\infty$ keeping $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ fixed.
- From the result you get use the fact that $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary to conclude the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it take $M- \epsilon < f <M$ and the result follows by continuity.